# Getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in my index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I am getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass in my index.html.erb, when I am implementing the elastic search functionality using tire in my model. What can be the possible reasons and solution for this?

index.html.erb:

```
    <div class="page-header">
  <h1>Friends</h1>

<%= form_tag user_friendships_path, method: :get do %>
      <p>
            <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
            <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
      </p>
<% end %>


</div>

<div>
      <strong>Friend list:</strong>
      <%= link_to 'All', user_friendships_path %> |
      <%= link_to 'Blocked', user_friendships_path(list: 'Blocked') %> |
      <%= link_to 'Requested', user_friendships_path(list: 'Requested') %> |
      <%= link_to 'Accepted', user_friendships_path(list: 'Accepted') %> |
      <%= link_to 'Pending', user_friendships_path(list: 'Pending') %>
</div>
<% @user_friendships.each do |friendship| %>
<% friend = friendship.friend %>
<div id="<%= dom_id(friendship) %>" class="friend row">
      <div class="span1">
            <%= link_to image_tag(friend.gravatar_url), profile_path(friend) %>
      </div>
      <div class="span7">
            <strong><%= friend.full_name %></strong><br />
            <% if friendship.pending? %>
            <em>Friendship is pending.</em> <%= link_to "Delete request", edit_user_friendship_path(id: friend.user_name) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.requested? %>
            <em>Friendship requested.</em> <%= link_to "Accept Friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(id: friend.user_name) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if friendship.accepted? %>
            <em>Friendship started <%= friendship.updated_at %>.</em> <%= link_to "Update friendship", edit_user_friendship_path(id: friend.user_name) %>.
            <% end %>
            <% if current_user.blocked_friends.include?(friend) %>
            <%= form_for friendship, url: user_friendship_path(friendship), method: :delete do |form| %>
                  <%= submit_tag "Unblock", class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
            <% end %>  
            <%end%>
      </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Model ( only the required code )-> user_friendship.rb:

```
    class UserFriendship < ActiveRecord::Base

include Tire::Model::Search
include Tire::Model::Callbacks


  def self.search(params)
     tire.search(load: true) do
       query { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
     end
   end

  attr_accessible :user, :friend, :user_id, :friend_id, :state

  belongs_to :user
```

Controller -> user_friendship_controller.rb

```
 class UserFriendshipsController < ApplicationController


    before_filter :authenticate_user!
  respond_to :html, :json

    def index


    @user_friendships = current_user.user_friendships.all.search(params)


    case params[:list]
    when nil
      @user_friendships = current_user.pending_user_friendships.all + current_user.accepted_user_friendships.all + current_user.requested_user_friendships.all
    when 'Blocked'
      @user_friendships = current_user.blocked_user_friendships.all
    when 'Pending'
      @user_friendships = current_user.pending_user_friendships.all
    when 'Accepted'
      @user_friendships = current_user.accepted_user_friendships.all
    when 'Requested'
      @user_friendships = current_user.requested_user_friendships.all
    end
    respond_with @user_friendships
  end
```

Comment: my guess would be that @user_friendships is nil - i.e. the user has no friends :(

Comment: Yes, very true. I also assumed the same thing. So in order to avoid the error I added <% unless @user_friendships.nil? %> exactly above <% user_friendships.each do |friendship| %> in index.html.erb but then this is blocking all my friendships in views means I am not able to get any data in @user_friendships which actually I need in order to display all the people who are added in my friends list. So  now what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is telling you that @user_friendships is nil when it is sent the each message. Presumably there is an issue occurring with how @user_friendships is being assigned in your params[:list] case statement. You'll need to figure out why @user_friendships is nil when the view is being rendered by troubleshooting this params[:list] case statement. I'd recommend debugging the application or logging the value of params[:list] / @user_friendships to see which case is being invoked and then figure out why the case being invoked is resulting in a nil value. Good luck!

Comment: I got rid of the error by simply adding <% unless @user_friendships.nil? %> in my index.html.erb file just before <% @user_friendships.each do |friendship| %>

Answer (score 1):

If you make your search method return an empty array `[]` rather than `nil` all should be good.

It could look something like

```
   def self.search(params)
     tire.search(load: true) do
       query { string params[:query] } if params[:query].present?
     end || []
   end
```